# Get the value of list<T> by string identifier

Tags: c#, list

I would like to get value of a item in List by just identifing the object with a string

```
string A ="some_string";              
listobject.Add(fruit[0].A);
```

```
public class apple
    {
        public string labbnummer { get; set; }
        public string red { get; set; }
        public string gren { get; set; }
        public string blue { get; set; }
        public string purple { get; set; }
}


public List<apple> fruit = new List<apple>();
public List<apple> rutten_fruit = new List<apple>();

List<string> myfruitlist = new List<string>();
myfruitlist.Add("green");  
myfruitlist.Add("red"); 


public void populate{

 while (reader.Read())
                {
                    apple tasty = new apple();
                    tasty.green = (string)reader["green"];
                    tasty.red = (string)reader["red"];

            if (list_nr == 0) { fruit.Add(tasty); }

}



public void orange(){

  foreach (var items in myfruitlist)
            {
               var A =items;              
               rutten_fruit.Add(fruit[0].A.ToString());                
    }
}
```

It does not accept listobject.Add(fruit[0].A); A as identifier

Comment: Unclear what you are asking or wanting to acheive

Comment: You need to use reflection for that, but that generally is a bad idea. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but it seems like you may want to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in some way.

Comment: I suppose the easiest thing to do is to add `fruit[0]` to `rutten_fruit`. If you actually want to add a string, make `rutten_fruit` a `List<string>` instead.

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the property indicated by `fruit[0].A`? Something like `typeof(Fruit).GetProperty("A").GetValue(myInstance)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can try using *Reflection* i.e. to find *property* by its *name*:

```
using System.Reflection;

...

private static T PropertyReader<T>(object value, string name) {
  if (null == value)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
  else if (null == name)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

  var prop = value.GetType().GetProperty(name);

  if (null == prop || !prop.CanRead)
    throw new ArgumentException($"property {name} has not been found.", nameof(name));

  return (T)(Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(value, new object[0]), typeof(T)));
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
listobject.Add(PropertyReader<string>(fruit[0], A));
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!! even if my question was not so clear you found exact what I was looking for. That what I will call expert! :) Thank you!!